# Issues Getting my GameObject to both Move Forward and Jump properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having an issue where my gameObject barely jumps at all. I think it has something to do with `moveDirection` because the jumping works when I comment out `p.velocity = moveDirection`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour 
{    
    public float jumpHeight = 8f;
    public Rigidbody p;    
    public float speed = 1;
    public float runSpeed = 3;
    public Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        p = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        p.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) 
        {
            p.AddForce(new Vector3(0, jumpHeight, 0), ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        Move ();   
    }

    void Move ()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Mathf.Clamp(180f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 360f));
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, -Mathf.Clamp(180f * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 360f));
        }

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0,Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveDirection *= runSpeed;
        }
        else
        {
            moveDirection *= speed;
        }

        p.velocity = moveDirection;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Any suggestions on how to fix this?" -- Comment out `p.velocity = moveDirection`?

Comment: I forgot to mention that while jumping works when I comment out   p.velocity = moveDirection, the object can't move.

Comment: Recommended reading: [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a much higher value for your jumpheight variable. I usually go with something in the hundreds.

Answer (score 0):

Because right after doing the `AddForce(...)` literally within the same frame you override the velocity with `moveDirection`. You should be *adding* to the current velocity, instead of overriding it entirely as such:

```
Vector3 velocity = p.velocity;
p.velocity = velocity + moveDirection;
```

This is exactly why [Unity warns against messing with velocity directly](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html), youd be better off just doing another `AddForce(...)` for your movement:

```
p.AddForce(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```

EDIT:

i don't like digressing too far from the OP's question, but your new problems are probably because you are doing too much with `moveDirection` half of what i don't even understand why but it should for the most part look like this:

```
moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0,Input.GetAxis("Vertical")).normalized;
float _speed = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) ? runspeed : speed;

p.AddForce(moveDirection * _speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Okay I tried both things and the jumping works fine but for the first one the object moves to far and the speed isn't constant when I hold the move keys and doesn't come to a complete stop  when I lift it, and for the addForce the Object doesn't move forward.

Comment: For LOLslowSTi I don't understand the float _speed line with the question mark and the runspeed : speed;

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out how to fix it. Instead of those MoveDirection variables I changed it to

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        transform.position += transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        transform.position -= transform.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed;
    }
```

and now it works just fine.